# How to Read an Integer from a Created File?

Tags: java, io, filereader, filewriter

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ReadInts ri = new ReadInts("mydata.dat");
    }
```

I've recently created a file called mydata.dat

What is the easiest way to call a data from the file using the Constructor, class and leaving the main method with that simply to read it?

The code that writes the file:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class WriteInts {
    private String fname;

    public WriteInts(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }

    public void write(int... a) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(fname);
        try {
            System.out.println("Writing to-" + file.getAbsolutePath());

            if (!file.exists())
                file.createNewFile();
            file.canRead();

        } catch (IOException x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedWriter outputWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            outputWriter.write(Integer.toString(a[i]));

            outputWriter.newLine();
        }

        outputWriter.flush();
        outputWriter.close();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int myArr[] = { 16, 31, 90, 45, 89 };
        try {
            WriteInts wi = new WriteInts("mydata.dat");
            wi.write(myArr);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I believe author is asking on how to read binary ints from DATA file. Needs clarification.

Comment: Yes, I already made a file, I just need to read it now.

Comment: Publish the code, which creates and writes file, please.

Comment: Published! I hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you an idea of how to proceed with your task:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadInts {
    private String fname;

    public ReadInts(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }

    public void read() throws IOException {
        File file = new File(fname);

        System.out.println("Reading from: " + file.getAbsolutePath());

        BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        String line;
        while ((line = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
            int integer = Integer.parseInt(line);
            System.out.println(integer);
        }

        inputReader.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ReadInts ri = new ReadInts("mydata.dat");
        ri.read();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [java.util.Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class in order to read your file. Specifically `Scanner#hasNextInt()` and `Scanner#nextInt()` methods.

Answer (score 2):

We can read like this

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("mydata.dat"));   
int [] tall = new int [100];
int i = 0;
while(scanner.hasNextInt()) {    
    tall[i++] = scanner.nextInt();   
}
```

Comment: Please do not give readymade code to OP. Give them hints to help them write code.